# How do we view images slideshow in fullscreen?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, images, image-viewer

I have a couple of images in a folder and I would like to easily browse through them at my own pace in Fullscreen.

Now I'm using Windows Photo Gallery but when i "play slide show" it keeps moving to the next image (which is not what I want).

I only want to move to the next image "at my own pace".

What solutions are there?

===============================

Windows Vista Home Premium sp2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the built in picture viewer in Windows, one thing should be able to do while in fullscreen is right-click the image and you should then be able to change the slideshow speed to slow. (Works on my Win7, I expect Vista to be similar)

After that the <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> arrow keys should allow you to move backwards and forwards between images.

Other than that you may have to download another image viewer such as [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) or [xnview](http://www.xnview.com/), I believe they both have similar options for fullscreen viewing and much more adjustable slideshow "speeds".

Comment: cool, there's a pause option. btw do you have any idea what's the shuffle for?

Comment: The shuffle option would be to randomly cycle through the images in that directory, akin to the shuffle on your mp3 player.

Comment: random.. lol of course not, i'm reading a book here.